# Understanding ActionFilterAttribute Checking For Null

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm trying to understand this ActionFilterAttribute. I've tried to play around with the code a bit to get a better understanding of how it works but i'm completely lost.

Here's the working ActionFilterAttribute. It is supposed to check for a null request body and return an error:

```
public class CheckModelForNullAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly Func<Dictionary<string, object>, bool> _validate;

    public CheckModelForNullAttribute() : this(arguments => arguments.ContainsValue(null))
    { }

    public CheckModelForNullAttribute(Func<Dictionary<string, object>, bool> checkCondition)
    {
        _validate = checkCondition;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (_validate(actionContext.ActionArguments))
        {
            var modelState = new ModelStateDictionary();
            modelState.AddModelError("Parameter", "The request body cannot be null");
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, modelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Why doesn't this produce the same results:

```
public class CheckModelForNullAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly Func<Dictionary<string, object>, bool> _validate = args => args.ContainsValue(null);

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!_validate(filterContext.ActionArguments))
        {
            filterContext.ModelState.AddModelError("Parameter", "The request body cannot be null");
            filterContext.Response = filterContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, filterContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the modified version enters the `if !_validate()` block?

Comment: OMG, there it is. If you look at the first one it's if _validate() vs the second one !_validate(). One has a condition if true, the other if not true. You're a genius! I've been lookin' at both classes for 10 hours puzzled and confused, damn that was a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Dumb mistake on my part:

```
if (_validate(actionContext.ActionArguments))
```

in the first class

```
if (!_validate(filterContext.ActionArguments))
```

in the second class.

The solution, remove the ! and it works the same.

Thank you haim770 for hinting at that! Guess i was tired and could not see that